# Application example of a Spring batch (JSR-352) on Data Flow Server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow, jsr352

I would like to have an example code of a Spring Batch application complying with JSR-352 (using batch.xml) running on Spring Cloud Data Flow Server as a Task.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56343203/run-spring-batch-jsr-352-application-on-spring-boot. _(see: [Discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56343203/run-spring-batch-jsr-352-application-on-spring-boot/56344227#56344227))_

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run Spring Batch (JSR-352) application on Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56343203/run-spring-batch-jsr-352-application-on-spring-boot)